# Serverless CMS On Lambda & DynamoDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm thinking to launch an open-source project to develop a serverless CMS working on top of AWS technologies. I want to have DynamoDB as the backend for storing data rather than having a simple markdown CMS. I want to know from the community here if this idea is reasonable and sounds good because I'm moderately experienced in AWS and so not fully firm about it and seek some help.

I will be developing the CMS in ASP.NET MVC Core served though Lambda. This CMS will have an external API which will be ASP.NET MVC Core Web API.

I also need some thoughts on the cost of running this CMS i.e. Do you think it will be cheaper to run as against the conventional CMS or if DynamoDB can squeeze a lot of juice!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very cheaper to run serverless than traditional software. There are tons of open source project that is on CMS serverless.

**Some of the prebuilt offerings**

- https://www.aerobatic.com/
- https://www.cloudcms.com/
- https://www.getshifter.io/  -- Similar to Wordpress with Lambda, S3 and CloudFront

**Open Source Serverless CMS:**

- https://cosmicjs.com/knowledge-base/serverless-cms
- https://nickmchardy.com/2018/03/building-a-serverless-cms-using-aws-and-hugo.html

a few to mention.

Make sure you google on serverless open source cms projects and contribute to any of the existing ones or make a difference by a creating an entire new CMS system.

Hope it helps.